# What is an attached bottom bracket?

Tags: bottom-bracket

Reading the specifications of a [Merida Reacto 500 (2015)](http://www.tredz.co.uk/.Merida-Reacto-500-2015-Road-Bike_74461.htm) I noticed that at the bottom bracket is `Attached`, I only ever read about brackets threaded in the frame or press fit brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Merida website list the crankset as FSA Gossamer Pro 52-36 386. FSA's web site show this to be a pressfit bottom bracket. Why it is spec'd as attached rather than pressfit I don't know. It is possible that this is how it was translated into English.